# Restrict the user input in a text field to confirm to a pattern

Tags: jquery

I've a text field with id countryCode in my jsp to input country code of phone number.
The user should be able to input country code as either numbers or numbers prefixed with a + sign.
eg: 91  or +91 or 1 or +1 etc..
Please suggest a jquery  function to restrict the user i/p as he types in, to accept only this pattern.

Tried using the below code.

```
$('input[id="countryCode"]').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[+0-9\b]+$");
        var str= $( "#countryCode" ).val();
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key) || (key=="+" && str.length>0)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But after entering 91,  I could not enter + as the first character

Comment: Use jquery  mask like that https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Do the mask min plugin has the flexibility to support the requirement - User may or may not enter + as the first character and the other characters will be numbers with no length restriction

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: Even changing to that won't work$('input[id="countryCode"]').on('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[+0-9\b]+$");
        var str= $( "#countryCode" ).val();
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key) || (key=="+" && str.length>0)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the typed character and it's position to determine if it is valid.  The check `(key=="+" && str.length>0)` is where it would fail if there already is content in the textbox and the user tries to type a `+` in the first position.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjw2j9as/2/.

HTML:

```
<input id="countryCode" type="text">
```

Javascript:

```
$('input[id="countryCode"]').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[+0-9\b]+$");
    var str= $( "#countryCode" ).val();
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else if (str.length > 0) {
        if (key == "+" && $(this).getCursorPosition() != 0){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

// Borrowed from: http://www.fourthbottle.com/2014/03/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textbox.html
 $.fn.getCursorPosition = function () {
    var pos = 0;
    var el = $(this).get(0);
    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
        el.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        var SelLength = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
        Sel.moveStart('character', -el.value.length);
        pos = Sel.text.length - SelLength;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart == '0')
        pos = el.selectionStart;
    return pos;
}
```